# Whats wrong with Scala encoding?

Tags: scala, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, sbt

I guess something is wrong with Scala while displaying "\303\251" unicode. Ideally it should display "Ã©" but instead it is displaying "ÃÂ©".

I tried with several scala versions like 2.10.4, 2.10.5 & 2.11.8 but i got the same output (i.e., ÃÂ©).

```
$ JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 sbt
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
> console
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_71).
scala> print ("\303\251")
ÃÂ©
scala> System.getProperty("file.encoding");
res2: String = UTF8
```

even i used equivalent hex escape literals for \303\251 i.e., \u00c3\u00a9, still the same output

```
scala> print ("\u00c3\u00a9")
ÃÂ©
```

Note: I face this issue only in Linux and Ubuntu OS but in MAC it works very fine as shown below:

```
scala> print ("\303\251")
Ã©
```

I didn't understand why scala is giving wrong output in linux & ubuntu machines. Does anyone faced this issue? Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: This is probably a Linux character encoding issue. I would guess that the underlying character coding in Linux machines interprets these characters differently than Mac.

Comment: Prints correctly from the REPL (2.11.7) on my Lubuntu 15.10 (Linux 4.2.0-34-generic) laptop. I do, however, get warnings that "Octal escape literals are deprecated."

Comment: What do you get when you invoke `echo -e "\u00c3\u00a9"` from the command line?

Comment: Scala 2.11.6 prints very well the characters in REPL

`code
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_40).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val x = "\303\251"
warning: there were two deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
x: String = Ã©
`

I think the problem is with the encoding in your OS

Comment: Hello @Jwh, I executed `echo -e "\u00c3\u00a9" `, the output is the same  `\u00c3\u00a9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Linux character encoding is the issue. After changing the environment variable LANG (as shown below), everything works properly.

```
/usr/bin/env LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/xterm
```